# How to remove a keyboard shortcut for sculp mode?

Tags: customization, shortcut

[image: #d view with the modes menu open showing the incorrect shortcut]

How to remove it. Please help!

Comment: Do you mean the **hotkey** of sculpt mode?

Comment: did you try restarting blender. It should be gone if you haven't changed the startup file or saved user settings.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File→User Preferences→Input→3D View→Object Non-Modal and delete the key for sculpting by pressing the 'x' beside it.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check it and sorry for messing it up previously.

Answer (score 1):

Go to file/user preferences

Then under input, change name to key-binding and search "left mouse"

[image]

Scroll to object non-modal and press the cross to the right of "left mouse"

[image]